# How to call a user-defined function at startup

Tags: vimrc

I've defined the following `tail` command to execute on a log file:

```
" syntax highlighting for log files
autocmd bufnewfile,bufread *.log set syntax=logtalk

" tail files with command :tail
function _Tail()
    set ut=100
    set autoread | au cursorhold * checktime | call feedkeys("G")
endfunction
command! Tail call _Tail()
cnoreabbrev tail Tail
```

And it works great: once I open a file and type in

```
:tail
```

It executes and tails the file. However, for some reason I can't get this to work when calling vim from startup. For example:

```
$ vim sql_actions_avails.log -c ':call _Tail()'
```

That doesn't raise an error but it also doesn't do anything. Actually, nothing that I tries 'does anything' unless I manually enter in the command within vim. What's the reason for this and how would I fix this?

The closest I've gotten so far is just to define a shortcut key in the vimrc:

```
nnoremap <C-t> :Tail<CR>
```

At least it's reliable!

Comment: Try `+` or `--cmd`; they happen *after* vimrc

Comment: `--cmd` gives me: `Unknown function: _Tail` https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#--cmd. let me try the other one.

Comment: huh, i had that backwards. Suprised -c didnt work

Comment: @D.BenKnoble what would be the syntax for `+`?

Comment: Just vim +command (you may need to quote it if it’s more than one word). But it’s the same as -c...

Comment: Are you sure it does nothing? What does `:au CursorHold` (to inspect it) says?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `--cmd` happens before processing any startup files and `-c` and `+` are really equivalent.

Comment: please check carefully that `-c` **does not do anything**. BTW: why are you calling `feedkeys()`? `feedkeys()` is really low level and should only be used, if you know what you are doing and other solutions do not work. Try using a normal command. Or try calling the function from a VimEnter autocommand.

Comment: your example works for me v8.2.1959

Comment: see in action: https://i.imgur.com/YLsmQPH.gif